# Parsing a json string in java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a json string of the format :

```
{"magha": {"2014-04-04 14:27:08.669217": "125"}}
```

I am not able to create a parser for the same. Looking forward for any help.

Comment: what have you implemented? Please show what have you tried.

Comment: String val={"magha": {"2014-04-04 14:27:08.669217": "125"}};
String val1=val.replaceAll("\"" , "\\\"");;     
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        ContainerFactory containerFactory = new ContainerFactory(){
          public List creatArrayContainer() {
            return new LinkedList();
          }public Map createObjectContainer() {
            return new LinkedHashMap();
          }};try{
          Map json = (Map)parser.parse(val1, containerFactory);
          Iterator iter = json.entrySet().iterator();
          while(iter.hasNext()){ System.out.println(entry.getValue());

Answer (score 3):

Download the [json-lib-jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.2.2/)

Use [**`JSONObject`**](http://www.json.org/java/)

Do like this

```
JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(yourjsonstring);
String magha=jobject.getString("magha");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I am sending random values of string. So it is not appropriate to use a specific value. Is there any other way to parse the specified json string?